# Parse SQL Query Text to Extract Table Names Used

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have a sqlite database that gets populated by a different process. This process generates tables in the db and fills them with data.

I am trying to apply a set of pre-written queries against this db, but I need to make sure that all of the tables referenced in the query are created in the db before I run it to prevent errors. I am trying to determine all of the possible ways that a table can be referenced in a SQL to make sure I cover all of the options.

simple:

```
select col1 from table1
```

joins:

```
select col1,col2 from table1 join table2 on col1 = col2
select col1,col2 from table1 left outer join table2 on col1 = col2
select col1,col2 from table1, table2 on col1 = col2
select col1,col2 from table1, table2 where col1 = col2
```

subqueries:

```
select col1,(select col2 from table2 where col1 = col2) as ag2 from table1
select col1 from table1 where col1 in (select col2 from table2)
```

alias:

```
select col1,col2 from table1 t1, table2 t2 where col1 = col2
select col1,col2,col3 from table1 t1, table2 t2,table3 t3 where col1 = col2
```

I am thinking to use a RegEx to identify the few occurrences.

```
from [table] [alias]
join [table] [alias]
from [table] [alias], [table] [alias]
```

This RegEx seems to account for most of the variances. Table names appear in group2 or group3:

```
(from|join)\s+([\w]+)|,\s*([\w]+)\s*([\w]\s*)?(on|where)
```

http://regexr.com/3aq8j

My questions:

- Have I identified all of the possible ways for a table to be used in a query?
- Are there any other false positives from my expression?
- I can't get all of the table names from the alias section. Help?
- Is there a better approach than RegEx?

I will be using this in Python code if that affects the format of the RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [*positive look-behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
(?<=from|join)\s+(\w+)(,\s*(\w+))?(?:(\s*\w+,\s*(\w+))+)?
```

*Note* that you need to use grouping correctly.In your pattern you have putted `from` and `join` within group so the result will be contain them.