# Spark: extracting list of table from spark sql query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any nice (and elegant, if there is..) way of extracting list of tables involved in transformation while using spark.sql(...) ?

I need dynamically identify list of tables (ideally without using customer parsing logic) in spark sql query and apply down stream transformations depending on table(s) involved.

I was thinking to use default SQL parser in

```
import spark.sessionState.sqlParser
```

but, I am just wondering if there is an easy way of doing this??

Comment: Is the sql query written by you or it needs to be extracted from somewhere (eg, from `explain` function)? Could you give some examples of how should extraction of tables work?

Comment: essentially, behind the scene I am registering some set of views using createOrReplaceTempView in the scope of the session, I want to know what view(s) involved in this specific sql query, I've notice that this information reachable in the debuger from resulting dataFrame via df.executionPlan.child.child.tableIndetifier (not sure 100% if its correct), but I can't  manage to create a code for this.

Comment: Do you want extract only list of table names or you would like extract any other details like LogicalPlan,catalyst expressions and etc ?

Comment: at this moment I just need list of table names, other details irrelevant

Comment: How about to use some regular expression on your query, like [Parse SQL Query Text to Extract Table Names Used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591622/parse-sql-query-text-to-extract-table-names-used)

Comment: regular expression would be not a reliable option, ANTLR4 library, around which spark sql parser build, have all this build in, I am just wondering if there option to use default SQL parser so I can extract this info somehow